# Why for(Class classElement : classes) assignment doesn't work?

Tags: java

Code1

```
    for(Class classElement : classes) {
        classElement = String.class;
    }
```

Code2

```
    for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        classes[i] = String.class;
    }
```

`Code1` end with {null, null} but `Code2` {String.class, String.class}. So why `Code1`'s assignment failed?

Comment: Or alternatively `Arrays.fill(classes, String.class)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your first example:

```
for(Class classElement : classes) {
    classElement = String.class;
}
```

is equivalent to this: (with `_hidden_i` being an "invisible" variable added by the compiler)

```
for(int _hidden_i = 0; _hidden_i < classes.length; _hidden_i++) {
    Class classElement = classes[_hidden_i];
    classElement = String.class;
}
```

which obviously doesn't modify the contents of `classes`.